# Property 'from' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.ts(2339)

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

The following code should have the result:

4

16

Done！

However, the VSC told me that : `Property 'from' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.ts(2339)`

I have no idea how to fix the problem. Could anyone help me please?

/*These code should be put into any component.ts file, then npm run start to see the result in the console.*/

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; 

constructor() {

    Observable.from([1,2,3,4]).filter(e => e%2==0) 
      .map( e => e*e) 
      .subscribe( e => console.log(e),
       error => console.error(error), 
       () => console.log("Done！") 
     ) 
}
```

Comment: have imported operators in your ts file?

Comment: which version of angular rxjs you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **rxjs** version 6+ they removed the `from` operator from the `Observable` class. So now you need to import from `rxjs` and use without appending the `Observable` class.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map, } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  description!: string;

  constructor() {


    from([1, 2, 3, 4])
      .pipe(
        filter((e: number) => e % 2 == 0),
        map(e => e * e)).subscribe(
          e => console.log(e),
          error => console.error(error),
          () => console.log("Done！")
        )
  }
}
```

**[Here is solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whvuff?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Hope this will help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please accept the answer so others will get benefit out it

Answer (score 4):

Import `from` directly

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';

from([1,2,3,4])
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html